# Pointers and local arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why doesn't my function printTable print the content of my array? For example, from the whole word 'oui' stored in my array `mysteryword` it prints only 'o'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define libraryDimension 12
char* getFirstElementPointerOfMysteryWord(void);
char getCarac(void);
void printTable(char*ptr,int dimension);

/* Main program*/
int main() {
    //getCarac();
    char *pointerForFirstElement = getFirstElementPointerOfMysteryWord();
    int tableDimension = 3;
    printTable(pointerForFirstElement, tableDimension);

    return 0;
}
```

This function is intended to provide a choice of words it has no parameters and it returns the address of the first element of my word's array.

```
char *getFirstElementPointerOfMysteryWord(void) {
    int randomNumbers[3] = {0};
    char mysteryWord[4];
    char wordLibrary[libraryDimension];
    wordLibrary[0] = '#';
    wordLibrary[1] = 'n';
    wordLibrary[2] = 'o';
    wordLibrary[3] = 'n';
    wordLibrary[4] = '#';
    wordLibrary[5] = 'o';
    wordLibrary[6] = 'u';
    wordLibrary[7] = 'i';
    wordLibrary[8] = '#';
    wordLibrary[9] = 'q';
    wordLibrary[10] = 'u';
    wordLibrary[11] = 'i';
    wordLibrary[12] = '\0';

    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0;  i<libraryDimension; i++) {
        if(wordLibrary[i] == '#') {
            randomNumbers[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    int index = rand() % 3;
    int randomNumber = randomNumbers[index];
    int k=0;
    for (int i = randomNumber ; i< libraryDimension-1 ; i++) {
        if(wordLibrary[randomNumber+k+1] == '#'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            mysteryWord[k] = wordLibrary[randomNumber+1+k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return mysteryWord;
}
```

This is the part where my code doesn't work properly.

```
void printTable(char *ptr,int dimension) {
    for (int i = 0; i <dimension ; i++) {
        printf("%c",*(ptr+i));
    }

}

char getCarac(void){
    char carac;
    carac = getchar();
    return carac;
}
```

Comment: Common beginner error. `return mysteryWord;`. That is wrong. `mysteryWord` is a local variable and goes out of scope (no longer valid) when the function exits. Any use of such a variable outside the function results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: thank you for your answer,should i then use it as a global variable or is there a way to manipulate it using only pointers?

Comment: You should make a copy of it before returning it (e.g., with `strdup`). By the way, why do you initialized the string variable in such a strange way? You can do`char wordLibrary[]="non#oui#qui#";`

Comment: No, don't use global variables unless there is no other alternative. They make programs inflexible and more difficult to understand. There are two general alternatives: 1. The caller passes in a buffer to the function. 2. The function allocates a new buffer using dynamic memory and returns that to the caller. Which one you use is up to you to decide.

Comment: The elements of `wordLibrary` are indexed `0` to `11`; trying to store anything in element `12` is writing out of bounds and leads to undefined behaviour.  A better way to do the initialization might be `char wordLibrary[] = "#non#oui#qui";` which automatically allocates enough space for the terminal null too.  Then you have the other problems to deal with.

Comment: Thank you for responding . can you please explain furthe how to use the buffer ?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable in a function, it is allocated on the stack. When the variable goes out of scope i.e. the function ends, the variable disappears (stack is local for the function) so by returning the address of the array you are returning an address that no longer exists.

Instead either allocate storage on the heap using malloc

```
char *mysteryWord = malloc(4);
```

or better, have it declared outside the function and then pass it to the function to fill.

```
void getFirstElementPointerOfMysteryWord(char* mysterword, size_t maxLen)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here

```
char *getFirstElementPointerOfMysteryWord(void)
{
    char mysteryWord[4];

        /* other stuff */

    return mysteryWord;
}
```

`mysteryWord` ceases to exist when the function returns.   Any dereferencing of it by the caller (e.g. examining its content) or passing it to another function that dereferences (which your code does) gives undefined behaviour.

You need to ensure whatever pointer the caller receives, it continues to point at something that will exist for the caller.   That can be done in various ways, each with different trade-offs.   Probably the easiest is for the caller to PASS an array with 4 elements as an argument to this function (if the caller owns it, it will not cease to exist until the current scope within the caller ends)